# Row of blocks - click on one and the rest slide off the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, slide

I have a row of blocks.  When one is clicked, I want the rest to slide off the screen and have the clicked box in the first position.

for example

[image]

I tried to mess with jQueryUI slide but it didn't seem to help.  Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5j7yhr0/) showing the original blocks. Maybe I need to position them differently than floating?  I thought about trying to move the distance left and off the screen but the animation looked awful.

```
$('.block').on('click', function() {
    $('.block').not($(this)).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500, function() {
});
```

Comment: Tiny typo: `this` needs to be `$(this)`. Also, you will probably have to come up with some animation to gracefully move the remaining block to the left edge of the parent, otherwise it will just jump there when the other blocks no longer take up space.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.block').each(function(item) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.block').not($(this)).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    })
  });
})
```

You still need to include jQueryUi, bellow jQuery, in order to achieve the slide effect.